# Java/Kotlin: Why does Jackson parse dates differently from SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, jackson, kotlin, simpledateformat

I'm sure this is some form of user error, but I can't puzzle out what I'm doing incorrectly.

I have a Kotlin data class that with a constructor field like this:

```
data class CronEvent(
    @JsonFormat(
            shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,
            pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    )
    @JsonProperty("time")
    val time: Date
 )
```

This gets populated by ObjectMapper that accepts a json string as a payload. For my unit test, I have a `SimpleDateFormat` object that I instantiate with the same pattern.

```
val jsonStream = CronEventTests::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("CronEventPayload.json")
val cronEvent = jsonStreamToCronEvent(jsonStream)
// ...
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
val expectedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("2018-01-15T00:48:43Z")
cronEvent.time shouldBe expectedDate
```

The json file (`CronEventPayload.json`) that I load in my unit test has the exact same date string (`2018-01-15T00:48:43Z`) yet my test fails.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: Mon Jan 15 00:48:43 MST 2018 but was: Sun Jan 14 17:48:43 MST 2018
Expected :Mon Jan 15 00:48:43 MST 2018 
Actual   :Sun Jan 14 17:48:43 MST 2018
```

They have the same input and are utilizing the same date format string, but they're clearly different. Why are these two dates not the same?

Comment: Can you paste your json file also ?

Comment: It’s a time zone issue. `2018-01-15T00:48:43Z` denoted 0:48:43 UTC, but is parsed as 0:48:43  MST.

Comment: I don’t think you should bother with the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class and the likewise outdated `Date`. I don’t myself have experience with using the modern Java date and time API with Jacksom, but it’s possible. See for example [Correctly handle JSR-310 (java 8) dates with Jackson](https://geowarin.github.io/jsr310-dates-with-jackson.html). Search for more, also on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The `Z` means zulu time zone or offset zero from UTC. You should parse it as such. `Instant.parse()` will do it correctly without an explicit formatter. `Instant` is the class from `java.time` AKA JSR-310 that you should use instead of `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timezone for `@JsonFormat` is `UTC`. You can override with the `timezone` attribute of the annotation.

The default timezone for `SimpleDateFormat` is your local timezone (`MST`, reading from your output)

Make sure that the timezones match. You can add the line:

```
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

just below the construction of your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Although your dates in their text format contains the timezone (the `Z` at the end, meaning `UTC`), you're using a format that just treats the Z as a literal character, you're not interpreting it as a timezone.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. I was afraid that might have been the issue, since all the examples that were parsing UTC dates in the same manor were escaping the Z like the T. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn't seem to offer an out of the box solution to parse the `Z` as a timezone, so this is the best option for the moment. Thanks

Comment: @PaulNelsonBaker `java.time.Instant.parse( “2018-01-15T00:48:43Z” )`